# Why does -sizeWithFont: return different results in code and debugger?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, lldb

This line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize([@"Test" sizeWithFont:((id)[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f])]));
```

prints the correct result: `{24, 15}`.

However, when I do the same in the debugger (GDB or LLDB doesn't matter) I get a totally different result:

```
(gdb) p (CGSize) [@"Test" sizeWithFont:((UIFont*)[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f])]
$1 = {
  width = 0, 
  height = 0
}
```

This happens on both the simulator and the device and on both the 5.1 final SDK as well as the 6.0 beta 3 SDK.

Any idea?

Comment: I can confirm I see the same Xcode 4.5 DP2 & 4.4 DP7. I cohaven't tested with 4.5 DP3 or 4.4 GM. Should I?

Comment: Are you using this code while printing gdb :
CGSize tempSize = ([@"Test" sizeWithFont:((UIFont *)[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f])]);
NSLog(@"width : %f  and   height : %f, ", tempSize.width , tempSize.height);

Comment: @Vaibhavi: Don't understand what you mean. Your code also prints the correct result while run regularly. This way it can't be executed in GDB of course.

Comment: @StuFFmc: No, I don't expect it to yield any different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, digging deeper, I found that the dynamic allocation of UIFont objects somehow fails in the debugger:

```
(gdb) p (CGFloat) [[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] pointSize]
$3 = 0
(gdb) po [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]
<UICFFont: 0x8e4b720> font-family: ".Helvetica NeueUI"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 0px
```

So for some reason, the font objects created in the debugger environment have a font size of 0. The other attributes look good.

I have logged this as a bug: [rdar://11934937](http://openradar.appspot.com/11934937)